# JavaScript Regexp match with negative lookahead

Tags: javascript, regex

I have following string:

```
<ul>
  <li>first</li>
</ul>

something

<ul>
  <li>second</li>
</ul>
```

I want to match content of both `<ul>` tags, but not string between first opening `<ul>` tag from first list and closing `</ul>` tag from second string. How can I achieve that? Obvious choice for me was regular expression with negative lookahead, but it seems I can't create correct regexp. I've tried this: `/<ul>([\s\S]+(?!<ul>))<\/ul>/gm`, so "look for any character between `<ul>` and `</ul>` tags with one or more occurences, if it is not followed with `<ul>` characters", but it doesn't work. https://regex101.com/r/PbT1QA/1

Comment: `/<ul>([\s\S]+?(?!<ul>))<\/ul>/`

Comment: Brilliant - thank you. Post answer if you like/want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Greedy vs lazy capture. I just added a `?`

```
/<ul>([\s\S]+?(?!<ul>))<\/ul>/
```